# Not storing in the array

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my page I have:

```
        function grabProfiles(searchstring) {
            $.post('newsletter.php?mode=grab', { search: searchstring }, function(data) {
                $('#newsletter_receivers').html(data);
            });
        }
        $('#newsletter_searchprofiles').bind('keyup', function() {
            var searchstring = this.value;
            grabProfiles(searchstring);
        });
        $(document).ready(function() {
            grabProfiles('');
        });
```

This outputs the result in div element #newsletter_receivers. The result looks something like this:

```
<div class="receiver">
 Peter
</div>
<div class="receiver">
 Maria
</div>
<script>
$(".receiver").click(function () {
$(this).toggleClass("newsletter_receiver_highlight");
});
</script>
```

So when you click on one of the receivers, they will be highlighted. This works fine.

Now I would like to put the receiver's id attribute value (the highlighteds id value) in an array. And then alert this arrays value when you click on a submit button that exists under the #newsletters_receivers. (not in the ?mode=grab where all the .receiver elements is)

I did like this:

```
         $('#newsletter_send').click(function(){
                 alert($('div.newsletter_receiver_highlight').length+' Selected');
                var arr = [];
                $('div.newsletter_receiver_highlight').each(function(){
                    arr.push(this.id);
                });
                alert(arr);
         });
```

This gives me two alerts. The one is right, it gives me the numbers of how many is highlighted. The second alert which should give me the values, is empty!

This worked previously when I did not made a ajax request to output the receiver elements.
And i think it is empty because first time the page doesnt contain anything in #newsletters_receivers , until it makes the ajax request. But how can it tell the right length then?

How can i fix/ make a solution for this in order to work?

// Conclusion question:

**Why is each() not live? and alternatives than this method?**

example:

```
$('div.newsletter_receiver_highlight').each(function(){
    arr.push(this.id);
});
alert(arr);
```

this stores value for all the CURRENT elements with the class newsletter_receiver_highlight

If i append a div element with class newsletter_receiver_highlight later from an request response, it wont store to the array

Answer (score 0):

If something doesn't work in first place always try a different approach. I would use `map` to get the array of ids.

```
var arr = $('div.newsletter_receiver_highlight').map( function() { return this.id; } ).get();
```

This comes instead of `.each()`

Comment: Where should i have this? I tried to alret(arr) it under the alert that shows the selected. Gives me [Object object] .. And please see updated question maybe it helps more

Comment: Actually my solution was incomplete. Missed the `.get()`

Comment: ok tried this, the array is empty, i get nothing in the alert. just like the each()